# I am looking for a vb.net library to handle json

Tags: vb.net, json

I am looking for a vb.net library where I can insert data into an object and have it spit out a json formatted string, and also take the string in again to rebuild the object.

I am not that concerned with mapping it to preexisting objects.

I have searched around and every single library I've found either can't read the strings in again, interprets them as one long string instead of breaking them up into parts, or fails to work entirely (asp.net can't even find any public members).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the inbuilt [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)?

It has functions that both serialize (turn your object into a JSON string) and deserialize (turn your JSON string into an object).